# Implicit Casting vs Explicit Casting

Tags: java, casting

here the bit depth of int and float is same where implicit casting is done
and in second one bit depth of char and short is same but explicit casting is done. What is the reason behind this ?

Implicit Conversion

```
int k = 100; //32bits

float l = k ; //32bits
```

Explicit Conversion

```
 char e = 'B'; //16 bits

 short f = (short)e; //16 bits
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `short` and `char` are both 16 bit (2-byte) variables their ranges differ.

> Char is an unsigned variable.
>
> Short is a signed variable.

The range of the a char type is from 0 up to 65535).

The range of a short is from (−32,768 up to 32,767).

Because of this difference java forces you to cast explicitly because a char that has value over 32,767 that is casted to a short can lead to an invalid conversion. The same goes for a negative short cast to a char.

This is also the reason you cast an int to long (since the value of an int will always fit in a long. But you have to explicitly cast a long to an int (telling the compiler that you are willing to accept the risk of dataloss / corruption)

Answer (score 2):

In java widening type conversions are implicit and narrowing type conversions are explicit.
Even though their sizes are equal.

Date type heirarchy is as follows,

`byte-->short-->int-->long-->float-->double`

You can refer to the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html)